# How to use the Capistrano Deploy folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

```
Rails 5.2.3
Capistrano 3.11
```

I am learning how to use Capistrano, but at this stage, not sure how to use the deploy folder. When I installed the capistrano-rails gem, it created several things:

1. config/deploy folder, with production.rb and staging.rb files
2. config/deploy.rb file
3. Capfile

Can I keep the config/deploy.rb file empty, and put the scripts in the individual files under config/deploy (production, staging, etc), and then assume that when I do:

```
cap staging deploy
```

And assume that it will use the deploy/staging.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### deploy.rb

Contain common configuration of your deployment scripts. like
puma configuration, repo url, sidekiq etc.

ex.

```
set :repo_url,        'repo_url.git'
set :application,     'app_name'
set :user,            'app'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        true
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/var/deploy/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
set :bundle_flags, '--deployment'
set :sidekiq_config, -> { File.join(shared_path, 'config', 'sidekiq.yml') }

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml", ".env"
set :linked_files, %w{.env}
# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system", "public/uploads", "vendor/bundle", "bundle"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/#{fetch(:branch)}`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
   task :restart do
     on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
       # invoke 'puma:restart'
     end
   end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end
```

### config/deploy/staging.rb

This file contain environment and server specific configuration.

```
server '1.2.1.255', user: 'ubuntu', roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true, ssh_options: { forward_agent: true }
set :rails_env, :staging
set :rack_env,  :staging
set :stage,     :staging
set :branch,    :staging
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: In staging.rb, branch refers to my GitHub repo's staging branch?